# Compactness of a subspace of $L^{2}([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

Let's consider the following space $K \subset L^{2}[0, 1]$, consisting of fucntions $x(t)$ so that $\sin{t} \leq x(t) \leq t$. How to check, whether this subspace is compact in $L^{2}[0, 1]$ or not.

I suppose that it's not, since it's relatively 'big' to be a compact space. Since, the reasonable approach is to suggest a counterexample, including sequence of functions so that it's impossible to extract convergent subsequence.

Some useful techniques, such as Arzela-Ascoli theorem, do not help much, since it's impossible to make accurate estimates from the given data.

Are there any hints that might help?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: First, let $E$ be the set of $f\in L^2([0,1])$ such that $|f|\le1$. Then $E$ is not compact (hint: trig functions...)

Now, there exists a rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ contained in $\{(t,s):0\le t\le 1,\sin(t)\le s\le t\}$. Hence, given a sequence $f_n$ in $E$ with no convergent subsequence you can construct a sequence in $K$ with no convergent subsequence, by simply...

Comment: C.Ullrich ... restricting them on the rectangle?

Comment: That might work, but there's something easier. You said you just wanted a hint...

Comment: Come to think of it. given $f$ defined on an interval, talking about "restricting" $f$ to a _rectangle_ makes no sense. So that can't be exactlly what you meant - possibly what you meant _is_ what I had in mind.

Comment: Well, i have expressed what i wanted to say quite incorrectly: we take our sequence $\{f_{n} \} \in E$ without convergent subsequence and for each $n$  restrict $f_{n}$  on $[a,b] \subset [0, 1]$, outside $[a,b]$ we make it equal to $0$.

Comment: That can't work - the new function will not be in $K$. Here's a question: What's the example for $E$, and why does it work?

Comment: For example, for $L^{2}[0, 2\pi]$ the seeking space is $(2\pi)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \pi^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cos{nx}, \pi^{-\frac{1}{2}} \sin{nx}$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In order to make it work for $L^{2}[0, 1]$ we just need to make a shift. ($E$ is an orthogonal basis in $L^{2}[0, 2\pi]$).

Comment: A horizontal shift and a dilation. Also some sort of change in the vertical direction...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_n :n\in N\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $L^2[1/2,1]$ with $n\neq m\to e_n\ne e_m,$ such that $A=\{\sup \{|e_n(x)| :x\in [1/2,1]\}<\infty$ for every $n$. (For example, a commonly used base of  certain cos and sin functions.) $$\text { For }x\in [0,1/2) \text { let } f_n(x)=x.$$ $$\text {For } x\in [1/2,1] \; \text {let } f_n(x)=\frac {1}{2}(x+\sin x) +\frac {1}{2}\frac {e_n(x)}{A}\ ( 1/2- \sin (1/2)).$$  We have $f_n\in E$ because $x-\sin x$ is increasing. But in $ L^2[0,1]$ we have $\|f_n-f_m\|=\frac{1/2-\sin (1/2)}{A\sqrt 2}$ whenever $n\ne m.$